# OpenSSL SSL_CTX_NEW returns "null ssl method passed"

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy

The code:
`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL( ASMTP.IOHandler ).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv23,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`

Seems like the problem lies down in method TIdSSLOptions.SetSSLVersions, if you set anything but a single version, it sets `fMethod := sslvSSLv23`. If not available, TIdSSLContext.SetSSLMethod returns nil and you get this error.

Indy Dec-2015, TIdSSLContext.SetSSLMethod can return nil.
Solution reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the question? None, hope someone finds this useful.

This is a Q&A site.  Sharing knowledge is fine, but it must be in a Q&A format. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

In any case, this sounds more like a bug report that should have been reported to [Indy's issue tracker](https://github.com/indySockets/indy/issues) instead of a public forum.

That being said, you should NEVER enable the SSLv2 or SSLv3 protocols at all, as they are no longer secure, and are not even available in many OpenSSL releases anymore. And SSLv23 is just a wildcard, it is meant to be used only in the `Method` property, not in the `SSLVersions` property (in fact, if you try to specify it with any other version, it will just be ignored).  You should be using only the TLSv1+ protocols in `SSLVersions`, let Indy deal with SSLv23 internally as needed.

```
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL( ASMTP.IOHandler ).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]
```

> Seems like the problem lies down in method TIdSSLOptions.SetSSLVersions, if you set anything but a single version, it sets fMethod := sslvSSLv23.

As it should be, because the SSLv23 method is how OpenSSL enables dynamic version negotiation during the SSL/TLS handshake, allowing client and server to negotiate the highest TLS version they both support.  Otherwise, if the client uses just a specific version, and if the server doesn't support that version, the TLS handshake Wil fail.

> If not available, TIdSSLContext.SetSSLMethod returns nil and you get this error.

First off, `SetSSLMethod()` will never return `nil` to `SSL_CTX_new()`.  If the requested method is not supported by OpenSSL, `SetSSLMethod()` raises an `EIdOSSLGetMethodError` exception instead.

Second, this condition means you can't perform version negotiation, so you must use a specific TLS version instead.  The exception is by design, letting you know that you asked for negotiation but your OpenSSL release doesn't support it, so try something else.

> The simplest workaround is to set Method after setting SSLVersions

The `Method` and `SSLVersions` properties are mutually exclusive, setting one updates the other.  However, `Method` is deprecated, you really should be using only `SSLVersions`, even for single TLS versions.

> That might not exist either, so a better workaround might be in indy:

Your workaround disables version negotiation altogether when SSLv23 is requested.  That is not a viable option for Indy to implement.

The real workaround would be for your own code to catch the `EIdOSSLGetMethodError` exception when SSLv23 is not available, and then you can re-attempt your connection using single TLS versions as needed.  No changes to Indy's code are needed for that.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I stand corrected. Originally I intended to ask what does SSLv23 mean and why would it be unassigned, but then was 4am, square eyes and came up with this "solution". `SetSSLMethod()` returning nil would mean that the app was built with much older Indy, but newer than the one shipping with D2007, which doesn't have SSLVersions property. Still no clue why would SSLv23 be unassigned.